# Cron API: is there such a thing?

Tags: linux, cron

Is there such a thing as a Cron API?

I mean, is there a programmatic way of adding/removing Cron jobs without stepping onto Cron's toes?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

UNIX cron's API is the filesystem. There is a `crontab` command for installing/editing user crontabs. The main reason for the crontab command is to enforce security restrictions on users (e.g., `/etc/cron.allow` and `/etc/cron.deny`).

System cron tabs are just files placed in /etc/cron.d (and cron.daily/weekly/monthly). No special care is needed; just drop the file in place. To quote the top of `/etc/crontab`:

```
# /etc/crontab: system-wide crontab
# Unlike any other crontab you don't have to run the `crontab'
# command to install the new version when you edit this file
# and files in /etc/cron.d. These files also have username fields,
# that none of the other crontabs do.
```

The format is the same as user crontabs, documented in crontab(5), but with a user field right before the command. Where SPACE means whitespace (one or more) and both 0 and 7 mean Sunday:

> *minute* SPACE *hour* SPACE *day-of-month* SPACES *month* SPACE *day-of-week* SPACE *user* SPACE *command*

Using normal POSIX file access won't step on cron's toes. Remember, [rename](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/rename.html) will always have the target name pointing to either the old or new file, never to nothing. So you can write the file to a new name and then rename it over top your old one.

Many programming languages have APIs to help with writing crontabs. For example, [CPAN (Perl) has several](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=crontab&mode=all).

Comment: So if I drop a file in /etc/cron.d/, it will get picked up by cron on its next iteration no harm done? I don't need to go through crontab?

Comment: @Jean-Lou Dupont: Correct. You can just drop the file in /etc/cron.d.

Answer (score 4):

[Augeas](http://augeas.net/index.html) has a [Cron module](http://augeas.net/docs/references/lenses/files/cron-aug.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely wrap around it. See the [Whenever](http://github.com/javan/whenever) ruby gem.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are referring to a web-based API, we have built a REST API that your web app can use to trigger callbacks/webhooks with. Check out [SaturnAPI's Cron](https://saturnapi.com/guide). You make HTTP requests to schedule, view and delete jobs. Below is an example for scheduling a job:

```
curl -X POST \
  https://saturnapi.com/cron/jobs \
    -H saturnapi-access-key:'YOUR_SATURNAPI_ACCESS_KEY' \ 
    -d dateTimeUTC='2015:09:25 14:30' \
    -d dateTimeFormat='YYYY:MM:DD HH:mm' \
    -d callbackURL='https://your.verified.domain.com' \
```

Answer (score -2):

Not as such, though scripting a modification using crontab isn't that hard.  That sort of thing (working through text tools instead of expecting a code-level API to system facilities) is part of the Unix paradigm, really.

Alternatively, a pretty trivial "cron API" can be implemented using a quick script in whatever language you prefer and "sleep". :)